# How to pass parameters from one view to another in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a string inside a view that I need to pass to a second view.

Inside view1 I have

```
route('admin.olt.add', $id, $resp)
```

where $resp is the parameter I need to pass to the second view. My route file calls the controller that returns the second view

```
Route::get('/olt/{id}/add', 'OLTController@config_parameters_onu')->name('olt.add');
```

Is there any way where I can pass this parameter without adding it to the url?

Comment: [`session()->flash()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data) ...? [Read the Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I fully understand your issue but as I got it, you can add this variable to a session and then fetch it whenever you want in any view for instance

to add the variable to the session

```
session(['resp' => $resp]);
```

to fetch it back

```
session('resp')
```

and here is the full [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session) for better guidance

Hope that is what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

you should use an array of more than one parameter

```
route('admin.olt.add', ['id'=>$id, 'resp'=>$resp]);
```